# php page delay loading with image loading

Tags: php, html, ajax

i want to make my php page delay loading with some image(loading image)

such like

http://www.businessbee.com/wp-content/uploads/24534/loading_home.gif

i have 3 php page

from first page if click submit button, next page is loading.php page which

display loading image and 30sec later i want to redirect to

third page final.php.

redirection and delay function is no problem , problem is

when start to delay loading image is not showing..

i want loading image show to user while delay 30sec

```
<?php
$delaytime=30;
for ($x=0; $x<$delaytime; $x++) {
  echo " ";
  sleep(1);
}

header("Location: /final.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();

?>
```

Comment: This can't be done with PHP. U will need javascript, PHP will send output to the client AFTER everything is executed

Comment: I agree with @DarkBee,use **JQuery** for delay instead of php

Comment: so anyone help me Jquery? hint or reference thanks!

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh why jQuery? Infact, how would you do a delay in jQuery? JS does it fairly easily with [`setTimeout( code, delay );`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

Comment: @DannyHearnah check here: [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh that is for delaying animations/effects

Comment: sry,you're right.I tought it can be mixed with jquery.ajax()

Comment: Please try this link...it might help you a lot....
http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a meta refresh HTML tag in your 2nd page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='page3.php'" />
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0">
    <img src="loading_home.gif"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JQuery.ajax()` Method for submiting the form.[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jveldboom/c73MQ/2/) could help you better to understanding that